# pip missing for osx homebrew installed python3.5

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I use homebrew to install and mantain python installations on OSX

Since latest python3 update pip is missing.
The pip module for python2.7 is present while it is missing for python3

It would be nice to have some suggestions on how to install it so that it would not break at every python3 upgrade

Please note that the packages are installed using homebrew (eg. brew install pythonX.X)

Following are the system information:
OS: OSX 10.11.2 (el capitan)

python + pip installation status
- python2.7.11 + pip (OK!)
- python3.5.1 + pip (pip is missing!)

Following is the output from the command 'which -a python'
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Yes, pip is simply missing for python3  I also confirmed it doing >>help()  help> modules  and pip is missing from the list of installed modules

Comment: Can you add the ouput of `which -a python` to your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot @cel I just did, and I did not know about the '-a' option.

Comment: `python3 -m ensurepip` will bootstrap pip for you, After that `python3 -m pip install <pkg-name>` can be used to install packages.

Comment: Great! It just works. Thanks you a lot, did not know about ensurepip.

Comment: I got it working with a ```brew uninstall python 3```,  ```unset PYTHONPATH```,  ```brew install python3```

Comment: It worked by simply uninstalling python3 using brew through `brew uninstall python 3` like @MattW suggested. And then install it again, boring, but worked.

Comment: @cel your comment should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Same on High Sierra. Matt W's solution worked:

```
$ brew uninstall python3
$ unset PYTHONPATH
$ brew install python3
```

Another 6 minutes waiting... go grab a coffee.