# Installing hyperledger indy node code fails on python3 not being default on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-2.7, hyperledger

I am installing Hyperledger [Indy](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/hyperledger-indy) (sovrin) self-identity software per these [instructions](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/stable/docs/indy-running-locally.md).

I have Python2.7 installed via Anaconda 3. I also have Python3.6.3 installed that I downloaded and installed from [here](https://www.python.org).

I'm trying to install some other software that has a dependency for Python > 3.5.

I've tried several methods to change my default Python:

1. Per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x#18425592) I set it manual in current terminal window:

   alias python='python3'
2. Per same SO I vi .bash_profile and added:

   alias python='python3'

then `source ~/.bash_profile`

3. Set a link to Python3:

bc-computer:~ momi$ unlink /usr/local/bin/python2
bc-computer:~ momi$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python

but still continue to get the same error:

```
bc-computer:~ momi$ pip install indy-node-dev
Collecting indy-node-dev
  Using cached indy-node-dev-1.2.227.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    FAIL: Requires Python 3.5 or later, but setup.py was run using 2.7.14
    NOTE: Installation failed. Run setup.py using python3

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3f/sh6dr8wx6w720b1_w38f_fh00000gq/T/pip-build-ecZnYY/indy-node-dev/
```

I also tried setting up a python3 test environment per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243437/how-to-use-python3-setup-py-test-with-pytest-and-pyqt5):

```
python3 setup.py test
```

And got this error:

```
> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
> can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please note that I tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336852/setting-python3-2-as-default-instead-of-python2-7-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-5) which seems to be the non-duplicate answer but didn't work for me:

> The safest way is to set an alias in ~/.bashrc:
>
> alias python=python3

My environment:

```
uname -msra
Darwin bc-computer.local 17.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.2.0: Fri Sep 29 18:27:05 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.20.62~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

My OS:
High Sierra 10.13.1

```
which -a python
/Users/momi/anaconda2/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was to use pip3 rather than pip for my install command per Mike Mueller's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446910/pip-missing-for-osx-homebrew-installed-python3-5?rq=1):

```
pip3 install indy-node-dev
```

I assume that pip3 points to python3x rather than 2x.

Answer (score 0):

I have also installed Hyperledger Indy SSI VC using MacOs Python 3.6.3. It is working for for me. I could demo the VON Network. It seems that your machine environment still points to Python 2.7. There are different ways by which we can point to Python 3.6.3 through virtual environment. You can try those options.